# Nginx adds strange chars to file content after gunzip

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as reverse proxy.
And I have strange behavior with gunzip option.

If I add this:

```
        gunzip on;
        proxy_set_header "Accept-Encoding" "gzip";
```

file output after download looks this:

```
Age: 1
Via: http/1.1 ptv21 (ApacheTrafficServer/8.0.3 [uSc sSf pSeN:tUc  p sS])
Expires: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 16:38:47 GMT

1a8
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
```

Without gunzip, file looks this:

```
Age: 1
Via: http/1.1 ptv21 (ApacheTrafficServer/8.0.3 [uSc sSf pSeN:tUc  p sS])
Expires: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 16:41:27 GMT

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
```

see that line "1a8", this wasn't in orginal file.

the characters also may be 1aa, 1a9

Why nginx adding thoose? Some of my STBs can't understand m3u8 file with theese character.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the upstream servers are not adding those characters?

Comment: @Piotr Yes, I'm sure.